# multi thread serial ports

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, modbus

I am trying to multi thread in serial ports. Say that I have X serial port. Each port has Y devices(modbus).I am taking out data from each device. To take out data from the device I need to send a message, then wait for the respond. I would like to speed up the application, that is why I would like to multi thread in it.

Is it possible to send and wait for multiple messages in one serial port?

Regards
Daniel

Comment: "Multi thread" seems like the wrong buzzword to use.  Seems like you are trying to *multiplex* or use *multidrop*.  **RS-485** is a serial protocol designed for a single master device with multiple slave devices connected to a single serial comm line; each device is addressed as a "drop", hence "multidrop".  **Modbus** apparently is also a multidrop protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not.  The serial port doesn't orgainze the data in such a way. It just takes bytes in and allows you to take bytes out in a sequential manner.  Attempting what you're asking will not work.  You'll get garbled serial port data, if not outright errors.  There's just no way to say "These bytes belong to that message".

Sorry, that's just the basic design of [how they work](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/serial-port.htm).

Comment: Thank you, at least I wont spend more time on it to try to figure it out:P

Comment: OP mentions **Modbus**, but your answer seems to focus exclusively on **EIA/RS-232** without stating this distinction.  Modbus, like other multidrop protocols, uses addressable packets to determine recipients and senders.

Comment: True, but the use of the serial link makes it impossible for the master to do anything more than sending one single request and then wait for the reply.